# Submitting multiple tab content via a form .submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have an API that receives all the data from a single page form that allows a user to send a message. The API is called when the user clicks 'Submit', which triggers the form submit.

I am currently in the process of adding in multiple tab functionality, so a user can create and send multiple messages within tabs.

Is there a way to submit each of the individual tab content and cycle through each of the tabs whilst only clicking 'Submit' once?

Here's an example of tabbed content that a user might create: http://www.bootply.com/61679

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can. What matters is where you place your form tag. In your case, since you want to submit all the tabs together, you would place your `<form>` tag in such a way that it covers all the fields inside `.tab-content`.

```
<form id="api-form" method="post" action="">
 <div class="tab-content">
   <!-- ... -->
 </div>
 <!-- Submit button -->
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

Also, the fields should have the same name with `[]` suffixed to it.

`<input type="text" name="message[]">`

This way you can hold multiple values with the same name. Not sure how you would call this on ruby-on-rails but you'll need to loop through them.

Comment: Actually, I need to submit each tab separately. I can't send them all at once.

The tabs actually sit in a much larger form though that have content shared by the tabs. The message within each tab is the only unique part about them.

Comment: @iamryandrake Strike my last comment. If you have to submit each tab separately, you can append `<form>` tags with the _submit_ button inside the tag around the fields in each tab. Like `<form><input type="text"><input type="submit"></form>` -> similar layout in each tab.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp).

Step-1) Define a javascript function for the submit button.

Step-2) Get the message content from each tab in that function and
    send it to your server using ajax.

Step-3) Just call the defined function on OnSubmit attribute of the
    form tag or you can use OnClick attribute of the button tag  too.

By this method you can even send these messages to multiples urls simultaneously using a single button.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first) is a demo for using ajax.

In the demo only 1 GET request is sent.

Similarly multiple GET or POST request can be sent using a single function.